# Перестаёт работать трансляция в pygame через socket

Tags: python, сокет, pygame

Я решил сделать программу которая демонстрирует экран с одного пк на другой, но она работает пару секунд и прекращает работать, pygame не отвечает. Вот код:
Сервер:

```
import socket
import pygame
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import io

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = 4444

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)



conn, addr = s.accept()

def get_img():
    try:
        out = b''
        while True:
            
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data[:5] == b'DONE!':
                return out
            out += data
    except:
        return None

pygame.init()

try:
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        out = get_img()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(out)).resize((960, 540))
        pygame_image = pygame.image.fromstring(image.tobytes(), image.size, image.mode)

        


        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 540))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Demo")

        screen.blit(pygame_image, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Клиент:

```
import socket
import pyautogui

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = 4444

s.connect((host, port))

def send(stage):
    while True:

        first = stage * 1024
        second = (stage + 1) * 1024

        with open('s.png', 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

            if not data[first:second]:
                s.send('DONE!'.encode())
                print('Готово!')
                break

            s.send(data[first:second])
            stage += 1

while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img.save('s.png', 'PNG')

    stage = 0
    send(stage)
```

Comment: `if data[:5] == b'DONE!':` - эта проверка некорректна. Нет никакой гарантии, что recv начнёт читать входящий трафик ровно в начале слова. Несколько пакетов данных могут слепиться в один, или наоборот слово может оказаться разорвано на несколько recv'ов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как мне тогда сделать проверку? просто это единственное что я смог придумать...

Comment: `s.send(data[first:second])` - и пытаться делить файл таким образом нет никакого смысла, потому что сокет всё равно слепит файл обратно в один непрерывный поток (и слово DONE тоже слепит, да)

Comment: Перед файлом отправляйте 4 байта с длиной этого самого файла, тогда получатель будет точно знать сколько байт надо прочитать и какое число пихать в recv